JOINT_STATE_CONTROLLER:Poco exception=/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so: undefined symbol:_ZN3ros8TimeBaseINS_4TimeENS_8DurationEE3MINE
I'm using ros noetic (ubuntu 20.04) and running a gazebo simulation. My goal is to move some continuous joints via a external input (mouse or keyboard), by using a python script to handle the external inputs (the end link has a camera plugin that streams ok on rviz, the project has a lot of other things but i think thats irrelevant to my issue). From my research thats the way to move joints (Firstly make them moveable with the right configuration, then give commands with a python script):
(ill parse only some parts of my files in order not to have a huge question, tell me if you need more context)
LAUNCH FILE:
 <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find my_turtlebot_gazebo)/include/turtlebot3_description/urdf/my_turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro"> 
  
  <rosparam file="$(find my_turtlebot_gazebo)/include/turtlebot3_gazebo/my_yamls/camera_controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

  <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />
   
  <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" ns="/turtlebot3_burger" 
   args="camera_joint_controller joint_state_controller"/>

YAML FILE:
turtlebot3_burger:
    joint_state_controller:
        type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
        publish_rate: 20

    camera_joint_controller:
        type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
        joint: camera_joint
        pid: {p: 1.0, i: 0.0, d: 0.0}'''

URDF XACRO FILE:
<link name="camera_base_link">
  <inertial>
      <mass value="0.005" />
      <inertia ixx="0.001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.001" iyz="0.0" izz="0.001" />
  </inertial>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.0001 0.0001 0.0001"/> <!-- Make the collision box very small -->
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
  </visual>
</link>

 <joint name="camera_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_base_link"/>
    <axis xyz="1 0 0"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.2 0 1.35" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

<gazebo>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
      <robotNamespace>/turtlebot3_burger</robotNamespace>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

<transmission name="camera_joint_trans">
  <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
  <actuator name="motor_1">
    <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
  </actuator>
  <joint name="camera_joint">
    <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    <!--hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface-->
  </joint>
</transmission>

 <gazebo reference="camera_base_link">
    <sensor type="camera" name="camera_sensor">
        <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <camera name="camera">
            <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
            <image>
                <width>800</width>
                <height>800</height>
                <format>R8G8B8</format>
            </image>
            <clip>
                <near>0.02</near>
                <far>300</far>
            </clip>
        </camera>
        <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">

            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
            <cameraName>turtlebot3_burger/camera_sensor</cameraName>
            <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
            <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
            <frameName>camera_link</frameName>
            <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
            <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
            <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
            <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
            <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
            <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
        </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo>

So, after running my launch file, i get the following error:
[ERROR] [1722199556.166414737, 0.255000000]: Could not load class 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController': Failed to load library /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. 
Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros8TimeBaseINS_4TimeENS_8DurationEE3MINE)
[ERROR] [1722199556.166449894, 0.255000000]: Could not load controller 'joint_state_controller' because controller type 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1722199556.166460387, 0.255000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[spawn_urdf-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/akis/.ros/log/60ff6bf6-4d22-11ef-befe-2d42b0ada799/spawn_urdf-4*.log
[ERROR] [1722199557.166947, 1.252000]: Failed to load joint_state_controller

I have done this:
$ nm -D /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so | grep _ZN3ros8TimeBaseINS_4TimeENS_8DurationEE3MINE
                 U _ZN3ros8TimeBaseINS_4TimeENS_8DurationEE3MINE

Which means that the symbol indeed does exists in the .so file
and runned this:
$ rosservice call /turtlebot3_burger/controller_manager/list_controller_types
types: 
  - ackermann_steering_controller/AckermannSteeringController
  - diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
  - effort_controllers/GripperActionController
  - effort_controllers/JointEffortController
  - effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController
  - effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
  - effort_controllers/JointPositionController
  - effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  - effort_controllers/JointVelocityController
  - joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  - pos_vel_acc_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  - pos_vel_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  - position_controllers/GripperActionController
  - position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
  - position_controllers/JointPositionController
  - position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  - velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController
  - velocity_controllers/JointPositionController
  - velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  - velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController
base_classes: 
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase
  - controller_interface::ControllerBase

and this:
$ rosservice call /turtlebot3_burger/controller_manager/list_controllers
controller: 
  - 
    name: "camera_joint_controller"
    state: "running"
    type: "effort_controllers/JointPositionController"
    claimed_resources: 
      - 
        hardware_interface: "hardware_interface::EffortJointInterface"
        resources: 
          - camera_joint

have removed and reinstalled some of the used packages and have rebuild my workspace but nothing fixed it error, so im stuck right now and have no clue what to do. The problem is obviously related with the Joint_State_Controller that im using in my YAML file.
Have any idea why i get this error and how to fix it ? Thanks a lot !

I think you have found a problem with the binary repo build. That symbol is not being requested when I build the libjoint_state_controller.so file from source code.
As a short-term work-around, you can build the ros packages too: add the ros_controllers repo to your catkin_ws (these commands assume you're using directory ~/catkin_ws/):
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers -b noetic-devel
cd ~/catkin_ws
# the next command installs any dependencies that are needed
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash

Update: I have opened github issue 633 for this problem.

Yes I am facing the same problem as well. I did not face this problem when loading my robot xacro in Gazebo until after running the following line:
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-controller-interface ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-control ros-noetic-joint-state-controller ros-noetic-effort-controllers ros-noetic-joint-trajectory-controller

After which, when I run the same ROS launch file for Gazebo to load my robot with the joint_state_controller module, the following error occurs:

[ERROR] [1730889586.650895457, 0.047000000]: Could not load class
'joint_state_controller/JointStateController': Failed to load library
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so. Make sure that you
are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and
that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error
string: Could not load library (Poco exception =
/opt/ros/noetic/lib/libjoint_state_controller.so: undefined symbol:
_ZN3ros8TimeBaseINS_4TimeENS_8DurationEE3MINE) [ERROR] [1730889586.650948740, 0.047000000]: Could not load controller
'joint_state_controller' because controller type
'joint_state_controller/JointStateController' does not exist. [ERROR]
[1730889586.650968311, 0.047000000]: Use 'rosservice call
controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
[ERROR] [1730889587.652133, 1.048000]: Failed to load joint_state_controller

I read from other sources which suggested to uninstall ros-noetic and I have tried it multiple times but to no avail. Seems to me there is a possibility that the latest version of ros-noetic-joint-state-controller if it has been updated is actually broken?

Welcome to Robotics YC Ng. I'm afraid that on Stack exchange answers need to  answer the question. If you have a related question, it should be asked as a new question (ideally referencing this one). We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the Robotics question checklist.

Do an
sudo apt dist-upgrade ros-noetic-rostime
The issue is that the ros::Time::MIN symbol is missing in the version of ros-noetic-rostime that you have installed. The latest version fixes it.

I'm having trouble understanding what actually fixed this. The latest ros-noetic-rostime pkg is dated 2023-June-20, so that pkg hasn't changed for a while. However, both ros-noetic-joint-state-controller and ros-noetic-roscpp got updated on 2024-Sep-13. Is this the actual fix?
